# Reasons for migrating from MySQL 5.0 to 5.1

Tags: mysql, database, migrate

I'm using a rather busy MySQL 5.0 database. What are the main reasons for me to migrate to MySQL 5.1? Does it worth the trouble?

I use VS2008/.NET 3.5
Servers run as a MySQL cluster on Windows 2008 servers.

Thank you for your answers so far. To be more specific - I'm looking for answers such as the one by Quanssnoi, listing the features most important to him, rather than links to MySQL feature lists, which I of course read. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Top reasons for me would be [**partitioning**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html) and [**XPath support**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html).

Answer (score 1):

For me the most important new feature was row-based replication.

Here's a list of new features in MySQL 5.1: [What's New in MySQL 5.1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-nutshell.html) If you're not going to take advantage of these new features, and you have a production system running on MySQL 5.0, then moving to MySQL 5.1 might not be worth the trouble.

MySQL 6.0 (which is still in Alpha stage), on the other hand, brings a [slew of new features](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/6.0/en/mysql-nutshell.html) including utf16 and utf32 support, and a new storage engine called [Falcon](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/6.0/en/se-falcon.html).

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that DB dumps and loading of dumps works much better in 5.1 (5.0 has issues with those backwards compatibility comments). Notice I'm not referring to schema Backup, but dumps (different things).